# The files saved from Matlab are restricted by limited size

Tags: matlab

I use matlab 2019a,  I used to save big files easily using :

```
save('example.mat','-v7.3')
```

But from two days, when I try to save my files, the size of saved file is only 482,351 MB however I know that the size of file should be up to 4.5Gb !!  I tried to save also from the work-space and then choose `save`, but also the same size of 482,351 MB is saved. when I save two files, they are saved with everyone of them has the same size of 482,351 MB. however they are bigger than that size.

Comment: Data in matfiles is compressed by default. You can save with the `'-nocompression'` flag to save faster, at expense of disk space of course.

Comment: @rinkert you mean like that save('example.mat','-v7.3','-nocompression') ??

Comment: @New_student: The syntax is documented here, should be right: https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/save.html#d117e1282718